# Google Analytics segment to exclude source not working, though reverse does

Tags: google-analytics

Trying to create a simple segment to excludes a referral source retrospectively (a spam site called trafficbot.link) from all analytics views.

#### I **can**:

…set Traffic Sources > Source > contains / starts with / exactly matches, and it will correctly show ONLY the spam/fake accesses (the percentage of users and sessions on the right is refreshed in real time).

#### I can't:

…do it the other way around, i.e. use does not contain / does not exactly match / is not one of.
The total stays stuck on 100% of sessions.

Am I missing something obvious?

I note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54401227/763419) which has no input other than from the original questioner, suggesting Google say it's "not possible" to exclude existing requests - surely it is? Isn't that the whole point of segments? How are you supposed to filter out spam otherwise?

(I'm aware analytics filters isn't retrospective.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about segments but the link you entered refers to filters.

Anyway, retroactively you can apply a segment to see the data without the spam one, you can use an advanced `segment`, choose `conditions` and `exclude sessions` that `contain` for example `browser size` equal to `(not set)`.

https://www.fortop.it/journal/tieni-lontano-lo-spam-dai-dati-google-analytics/

Comment: Thanks. This worked with advanced segments (the quickest way to find Source / Medium is to use the search field, rather than expanding/collapsing the lists.)